Error while deploying input type date on typescript: Property 'showPicker' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'
I'm still encountering an error when deploying the app using showPicker in an <input type="date">. I added the latest version of the types (@types/react version 18.3.2) to try to fix this, but it didn't work. Could you help me out? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
On the repo in github the issue seems as closed, but I still have the problem (https://github.com/w3ctag/design-reviews/issues/688)
I've tried the try / catch as in the issue above mentioned, and to upgrade my @types/react from 18.0.17 to the newest.
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.3.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "vite": "^3.2.7"
}


Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be in your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] in the question. More: How do I ask a good question? and Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

In a previous question on this on April 16th (found with this search), in a comment user Mario Vernari says the latest TypeScript DOM types have showPicker (it's the TypeScript DOM types, not React's types, that are relevant to HTMLInputElement). I can confirm that if I bootstrap a fresh project, I see showPicker on HTMLImageElement. Have you made sure yours are up-to-date? (Basically: Make sure you're using the latest TypeScript.)

You're right. Thank you so much for the help. I'll try to be more clear in the next questions.

As @t-j-crowder comment, the error is fixed by updating the three packages related to typescript:
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.3.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.69.5",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "vite": "^3.2.7"
  }

With this config, the error does not occur.
